# _VFP.AutoYield = .F. initiates re-install of Foxpro program for non-admin users Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: activex, windows-server-2008-r2, visual-foxpro

VFP 9 program with ActiveX controls on Windows Server 2008 R2, running via Remote Desktop connection, works ok for administrators but when non-admin users load a form with an ActiveX control that has the line "_VFP.AutoYield = .F.", the Windows installer tries to re-install the program with a message about files in use.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a third-party ActiveX control, do you have the required licenses for it?

The case may be that the developer (or default) license allows the administrator account to run the control, but not using any other user accounts without the required license.